# Bayesian regression for the sum of Gaussians

Tags: regression, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I'm pretty new to Bayesian statistics and I want to use Bayesian regression on a 2D data set (frequency on x-axis and measurement data on the y-axis) to quantify the uncertainties. The model is a simple sum of multiple Gaussians (number of Gaussians = 10) with unknown parameters (amplitude, position, and width of the Gaussians). I am trying my hands on Bayesian Inference for Gaussian mixture models using PyMC3.

I am not sure if this is the right approach to proceed. Any leads on the same would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The term "sum of Gaussians" is [ambiguous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146903/relation-between-sum-of-gaussian-rvs-and-gaussian-mixture?r=SearchResults&s=14|79.5168) : the sum of independent Gaussian random variables is yet again a Gaussian random variable. The weighted sum of Gaussian probability densities is a mixture of Gaussian densities and [the number of entries on X validated only is enormous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixture+of+Gaussian).

Comment: Hey Xi'an, thanks for your comment. However, I am aware that I can use EM-algo to fit the mixture of Gaussians but I tend to focus more on Bayesian side of the problem.
Do you think carrying out Bayesian inference on multivariate Gaussian mixtures would be useful in this case?